# Linq - How to get row numbers from excel sheet

Tags: c#, linq, epplus

I'm trying to get all the rows from an excel sheet where a particular word is contained in said rows.

```
 var selectedrows = range
 .Where(x => x.Text == domain.Name).Select(x=> x.Rows).ToList();
```

`range` is the whole excel range

`domain.Name` is what the cell text has to compare itself to.
`x=> x.Rows` is what I thought would be the way to select the row numbers.
Instead it `selectedrows` is filled with only '1', times twelve. It should contain 1 to 12. It has the right amount, but not the right numbers to go with it.

Does anyone know a neat little way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want the *row numbers* when you already have the *cells* ?

Comment: Because the rows contain all kinds of data I need to add to my model. This way I'm getting the rows I need. There are 107 rows.

Comment: You already have them, as long as `range` isn't restricted to a single column. If it is, rewrite it so it *isn't* and compare against the proper cell value, eg `x[1,thatColNumber].Text==domain.Name`

Comment: In any case, in Excel even a Cell is a Range. You can get it's row with .Start.Row.

Comment: Another option is to use the `Offset()` method as shown [in this sample](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/291741bd5a8109ae479f1a30fcdb27c335216657/SampleApp.Core/Sample8.cs#L94) to get a cell value relative to the current one, eg `Select(x=>new {Name=x..Text, Field1=x.Offset(0,-1).Value, Field2=x.Offset(0,1)})`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos awesome, thanks for all these different ways! Didn't think of the first way you explained it.

Comment: Try following : var selectedrows = range.Select((x,i) => new {x = x, i = i})
 .Where(x => x.x.Text == domain.Name).Select(x=> new { rows = x.x.Rows, number = x.i}).ToList();

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If you put your comments as an answer I'll make sure to mark it as such.